# R: How to apply a function to a chunck in data.frame and return a converted chunck?

Tags: r

Consider X as a matrix or data.frame. Is there anything like 
    apply(X,1,FUN) 
which, instead of applying FUN to each row in X, gets some form like 
    myApply(X,INDEX,FUN) 
where INDEX is a factor or indexing vector  so that  for each unique value IDX in INDEX, FUN is applied to 
    X[INDEX==IDX,] 
and return some values?

Thanks

Comment: Please make it easier to help you by providing a [**minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) with some toy data, the desired output and the code you have tried. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you're looking for `?aggregate` and/or `?ave`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by splitting your data frame with `split` and operating on each subset with the `lapply` function. Let's assume you wanted to compute the maximum ratio of sepal length to petal length for each species in the iris dataset. You could do this with:

```
data(iris)
unlist(lapply(split(iris, iris$Species),
              function(x) max(x$Sepal.Length / x$Petal.Length)))
#     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#   4.833333   1.700000   1.352941
```

If you wanted to return multiple values for each subset, you can slightly modify the approach:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(iris, iris$Species),
                      function(x) data.frame(max.ratio = max(x$Sepal.Length / x$Petal.Length),
                                             min.ratio = min(x$Sepal.Length / x$Petal.Length))))
#            max.ratio min.ratio
# setosa      4.833333  2.526316
# versicolor  1.700000  1.176471
# virginica   1.352941  1.050000
```

This approach is called split-apply-combine.